# "Other" text box limit too small when rejecting edits

Tags: feature-request, documentation

When rejecting an edit in documentation you are given the option of selecting "Other" and then typing in an "Other" reason. This box states the following explicitly:

> A problem not listed above. Be specific and detailed!

However, the box itself only allows you to enter 150 characters. This is too small an amount to explain potentially nuanced issues with documentation editing.

Can we get the text box limit increased?

Comment: If it's good enough for Twitter, it's good enough for complex discussions of technical minutia. That's why all journals have moved to a Twitter based publishing model, right?

Comment: Twitter Morgan!? Luxury! Back in my day we used to have to reject edits by writing on the inside of a shoe.

Comment: I think it's the same length as the "Other" for suggested edits on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ryanyuyu yes I suspected that was probably the case, it needs to be longer for Documentation though, I think.

Comment: @ryanyuyu awesome, thanks for the dupe suggestion.

Comment: @Ffisegydd You had shoes?